# How do I send a put request to github api with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, github, github-api

I'm trying to close issues through the github api with an ajax call. I'm getting a 404 not found message.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/fakeName/some_app/issues/36?state=closed&access_token=my_key',
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(result) {
        alert("complete!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Is that an actual URL or a demo URL (fakename/some_app)

Comment: It's fake. I have it working now.

Comment: Note you should *never* use and share your token on the client side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/some_name/some_app/issues/23?access_token=some_number',
        type: 'PATCH',
            data: '{"state": "closed" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
```